# ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

Tags: python

I get the following error when running the code below.

> ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

The code is processing information from images sent to it from simulator.

It runs well at first but when the array `Rover.nav_angles` is empty i get the error although there is an if condition

```
if Rover.nav_angles is not None:
        Max_angle_points=np.argmax(Rover.nav_angles)
        MAX_DIST=np.max(Rover.nav_dists[Max_angle_points])
```

Comment: If the array is empty, it's still an array - it doesn't magically become None in that case.

Comment: Instead try `if Rover.nav_angles:`. You are explicitly testing for `None` and an empty list is a valid reference.

Comment: if Rover.nav_angles:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @AhmedGendy if Rover.nav_angles is a list, it can be empty but not None, use double check: `if Rover.nav_angles and not len(Rover.nav_angles)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
if Rover.nav_angles:
    ...
```

To check for emptiness and `None`.
But it seems that you deal with `numpy` array so use:

```
if Rover.nav_angles.size:
    ...
```

Comment: i get that : if Rover.nav_angles:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I'm guessing this is `numpy` array :)

Answer (score 0):

In python it is mostly conceived better to `try` things rather than setting conditions around it.

```
try: 
    Max_angle_points=np.argmax(Rover.nav_angles)
    MAX_DIST=np.max(Rover.nav_dists[Max_angle_points])
except ValueError:
    pass
   # specify what the code should do, if the exception occurs.
```

To your actual problem: `empty` does not necessarily mean that your array is `None`. If you want to check with a condition, try

```
if Rover.nav_angles:
    Max_angle_points=np.argmax(Rover.nav_angles)
    MAX_DIST=np.max(Rover.nav_dists[Max_angle_points])
```